# Liberty encrypted passwords are not working in Docker

Tags: docker, encryption, websphere-liberty

I am passing the datasource to liberty and running dokcer container.

```
My password = password 
[pser@7723sd6 bin]$ ./securityUtility encode "password#01"
{xor}Lz4sLCgwLTt8b24=
    
I copied the password '{xor}Lz4sLCgwLTt8b24=' to my setup.cfg



    db_schema="KA01"
    db_user="ka01"
    db_password="{xor}Lz4sLCgwLTs="
    db_driver="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
```

Note: In my local setup (IDE : eclipse and liberty) works fine but same does not work in docker container.

Comment: Can you try a simpler password... one without the "#" pound sign?

Comment: I tried the simple password also 'password' just this.

Answer (score 0):

Liberty by default uses server.xml to define datasources and won't process your file setup.cfg.  I'm assuming you have some plugins in your eclipse env that are allowing this to work in that env.  You can use encrypted passwords in the config of a Liberty datasource, see [Configuring database connectivity](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=liberty-configuring-relational-database-connectivity-in).  Simply replace the value of the `password` attribute with your encrypted value.

Comment: Hi Rowe, thanks for your reply. I read my configuration file (setup.cfg) values and copied them to datasource.xml and i am passing datasource.xml for server.xml. I am  passing the encoded password to setup.cfg as it is. i am facing the same problem, invalid user id and password error is coming.

Comment: You can't "copy" the contents of setup.cfg into an xml, the syntax is different and Liberty schema for config is not name/value pairs.  Pls share your server.xml and datasource.xml files.  Also, what's in the server logs/ffdcs?  Any exceptions/errors?